# What are these groups in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was poking around Pokémon Go and noticed the Pokédex Pokémon are in groups:

[image: Pokédex Groups]

What do these mean?

Answer (score 16):

Kanto, Johto, Hoenn, and Sinnoh are the names of regions in the mainline Pokemon games. It's shorthand for which Pokemon belong to which generation (although there are some exceptions here and there).

- Generation 1 (Red/Blue/Yellow) - Kanto
- Generation 2 (Gold/Silver/Crystal) - Johto
- Generation 3 (Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald) - Hoenn
- Generation 4 (Diamond/Pearl/Platinum) - Sinnoh

Comment: And if you click the groups, it will auto-scroll to the first entry for that region

Comment: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Region You've also failed to mention the remakes: FireRed, LeafGreen, and Let's Go! Pikachu/Eevee occur in Kanto, HeartGold and SoulSilver occur in Johto, and Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire occur in Hoenn.

Comment: @jpmc26 I didn't mention the remakes because remakes are typically in a different generation (Red/Blue are Gen 1 and FireRed/LeafGreen are Gen 3), they also usually don't add new Pokemon, and they don't introduce new regions (which is the salient part of this question).

Comment: If you're looking to emphasize the generations, I would add the generation numbers explicitly then.